# How to remove the anchor tag from parent class not from child class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am removing the anchor tag from the parent class which is working but it also removing from the child class. I need an anchor tag on the child class.

Would you help me out?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#left-side-menu li.menu-item-has-children a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

```html
<nav id="left-side-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="">Test 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Test 2-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test 2-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test 3</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) for CSS Selectors

Solution for your example

replace `#left-side-menu li.menu-item-has-children a` to `#left-side-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a` to detect the tag anchor link which locate directly inside `li.menu-item-has-children` element

final code

```
$(function() {
  $('#left-side-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

Comment: @Let me try this

Comment: Oh!..sliy mistake. Thanks for the help. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

> You can simply do this with CSS. Hope works for you

```css
.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav id="left-side-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="disable" href="">Test 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Test 2-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test 2-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Test 3</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't think so this is the best because anyone can check the anchor link using the inspect element.

Comment: Yes, in that case it's not works. I thought that you just want to display parent anchor with no linking.